# Can I use "keypoint" as a single word?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In the project that I'm currently working on, we often use so called "key points" - in image processing these are characteristic points (interest points) on images.

I'm wondering - is it okay to use "keypoint" as a single word instead of "key point"?

---

(PS I'm not into language-stuff, so I don't know what are the appriopriate tags for such question.)

Comment: If you want to verb the noun then yes, if you are creating a jargon term or using one which already exists then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: Indeed, I want only to use it as a noun e.g. `keypoint detection`

Comment: Maybe it's already an accepted jargon term? If it is you are good to go. Have a look at literature.

Comment: Good point, @Ben, I was wondering whether it is enough to say that word is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In technical or academic writing it is always acceptable to use the correct jargon terms for the field.

A quick search on Stack Overflow suggests that "keypoint" as a single word is in reasonably common use.

- Keypoint - 2400 hits: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=keypoint
- "Key Point" - 6250 hits: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22key+point%22

On the other hand, google searches combining "keypoint" or "Key point" with other image processing terms seem to suggest "keypoint" is somewhat more commonly used. Both are used in academic papers.

If this is for academic work you might want to copy what your instructor or lecturer does.

Comment: [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=key+point%2C+keypoint&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckey%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeypoint%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ckey%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeypoint%3B%2Cc0) also validates "keypoint" as standard in image processing (if you go into the results, image processing books are obvious).